# Excel Javascript API fetch position of multiple sheets

Tags: javascript, excel, office365, office-js, office-addins

How can I get the position of two worksheets using the `Excel Javascript API`?

Here is how it works just for one sheet:

```
Excel.run(function (ctx) {
    var wSheetName = 'Sheet1';
    var worksheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem(wSheetName);
    worksheet.load('position')
    return ctx.sync().then(function () {
        console.log(worksheet.position);
    });
});
```

=> it logs `0` to the console

But it doesn't logs anything if I try to get the position for two worksheets:

```
Excel.run(function (ctx) {
    var wSheetName = 'Sheet1';
    var wSheetName2 = 'Evars';
    var worksheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem(wSheetName);
    var worksheet2 = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem(wSheetName2);
    worksheet.load('position')
    worksheet2.load('position')
    return ctx.sync().then(function () {
        console.log(worksheet.position);
        console.log(worksheet2.position);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried your code, and it works fine.  I wonder if you simply didn't have a sheet by one of those names, and so it was throwing an exception -- which was appearing to you as silent, since you didn't have a catch handler.

The code below, essentially the same as yours but with a catch statement, works correctly:

```
Excel.run(function(ctx) {
    var wSheetName = 'Sheet1';
    var wSheetName2 = 'Sheet2';
    var worksheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem(wSheetName);
    var worksheet2 = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem(wSheetName2);
    worksheet.load('name, position')
    worksheet2.load('name, position')
    return ctx.sync().then(function () {
        console.log(worksheet.name + ": " + worksheet.position);
        console.log(worksheet2.name + ": " + worksheet2.position);
    });
}).catch(function(error) {
    OfficeHelpers.UI.notify(error);
    OfficeHelpers.Utilities.log(error);
})
```

You can try this snippet live in literally five clicks in the new Script Lab (https://aka.ms/getscriptlab). Simply install the Script Lab add-in (free), then choose "Import" in the navigation menu, and use the following GIST URL: https://gist.github.com/Zlatkovsky/c61594f1c86970e8dba91fe94b7ca4b6.  See [more info about importing snippets to Script Lab](https://github.com/OfficeDev/script-lab/blob/master/README.md#import).

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution [here](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/worksheetcollection) ... maybe this will help someone

```
Excel.run(function (ctx) {
    var worksheets = ctx.workbook.worksheets;
    worksheets.load('items');
    return ctx.sync().then(function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < worksheets.items.length; i++) {
            var sheet_name = worksheets.items[i].name;
            var sheet_position = worksheets.items[i].position;
        }
    });
```